# how to use index match when you have multiple values in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

Here i have used index match but i don't understand how to use for other values

```
=INDEX($I$2:$J$6,MATCH(D2,$J$3:$J$6,0),MATCH($E$1,$I$2:$J$2,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use Wild cards, but because `Manager` can be found in multiple we need to add some `,` to the front and back to get a correct match:

```
=INDEX($I$3:$I$6,MATCH("*, "&D2&",*",", "&$J$3:$J$6&",",0))
```

With older version that do not have the dynamic array capabilities, this formula may need to be array entered by using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If one is using Office 365 Excel or later we can use XLOOKUP with the same wild card search:

```
=XLOOKUP("*, "&D2&",*",",", "&$J$3:$J$6&",",$I$3:$I$6,"Not Found",2)
```

Comment: Copied his error of using `$I$2:$I$6` instead of `$I$3:$I$6` I believe, he's getting C for Executive while it should be D and A for Sales Manager which should be B.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Yup, good eye

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach could be using `LOOKUP()` Function :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(D2,$J$3:$J$6),$I$3:$I$6)
```

---

Note: As **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir pointed out that the output will return **[FALSE POSITIVES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives)** if ever the designation in column J is swapped i.e. Cheif Manager and Manager.

Comment: Alright Sir. Sir I was doing wrong. While applying the logic of wildcard in `XLOOKUP()` and realized later that i forgot to add the ", "& and &", " at the end.  `XLOOKUP()` also works, can you please add it in your post

Comment: Feel free to add it to mine if you want.

Comment: Sir understood found the issue.

Comment: BTW, XLOOKUP would not be appropriate here as the tag states it is for 2010.